# HTML: Anchor tag is converted to %23 on form GET request

Tags: html, forms, anchor

I have an html form and I'm trying to use an anchor tag in its GET request, so that the user will be sent to a specific part of the page. I have it set up like this:

```
<form action="www.website.com/page/" method="get">
 <select name="foo">
  <option value="bar#myAnchor">Sample</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The user is redirected to www.website.com/page/?foo=bar%23myAnchor.

Instead, I want to get the same result as the user following a direct link Link

I haven't been able to find the problem, but it seems like a browser issue since I can't get around it with an html entity or any other alternate coding.

What do you think?

Comment: That looks like the desired result (because normally you wouldn't want the form to behave that way). You'll probably have to use JavaScript to do this the way you want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use javascript.  A simple implementation might look like this.

```js
function goToUrl(){
  var url = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/' + document.querySelector('#urlSelector').value;
  window.open(url);
  //you could set window.location.href as well
}
```

```html
<select id="urlSelector">
  <option>bar#myAnchor</option>
</select>
<button onclick="goToUrl()">Submit</button>
```

.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Whenever we submit a form, the values are URL encoded. Hence, in your case, when the form is submitted, the URL becomes

```
www.website.com/page/?foo=bar%23myAnchor
```

If you open the network tab, you can see this is the encoded version of foo=bar#myAnchor

If you just want the user to go to a link, use anchor tags and change the **href** property based on your logic.

Hope that helps!